# dwp package gives me Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : !anyNA(x) is not TRUE

Tags: r, distribution, shapefile

I am using the dwp package to "Account for the Fraction of Carcasses outside the Searched Area
and the Estimation of Bird and Bat Fatalities at Wind Energy Facilities"
I add 3 shapefiles SP8_BOX, SP8, carcasses.

- SP8_B0X is a multipolygon with 3 columns at attribute table (OBJECTID, Turbine, Class)
- SP8 with Turbine column
- carcasses (Turbine, Species, Date)

```
`# import site layout and carcass observation distances from shape files
layout_shape <- initLayout(data_layout = "SP8_BOX.shp",
                           file_turbine = "SP8.shp", unitCol = "Turbine")
cod <- readCarcass("carcasses.shp", unitCol = "Turbine")

rings_shape <- prepRing(layout_shape, scVar = "Class", notSearched = "Out")`
```

layout shape and cod are created as normal, but prepRing gives me

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : !anyNA(x) is not TRUE
```

I have tried

```
lapply(layout_shape, is.na)
```

```
$layout
  OBJECTID Turbine Class geometry
1    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
2    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
3    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
4    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
5    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
6    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE

$layoutAdj
  OBJECTID Turbine Class geometry
1    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
2    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
3    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
4    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
5    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE
6    FALSE   FALSE FALSE    FALSE

$turbines
  Turbine geometry
1   FALSE    FALSE

$unitCol
[1] FALSE

$tset
[1] FALSE

$tcenter
        X     Y
SP8 FALSE FALSE
```

```
str(layout_shape$turbines)
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Turbine : chr "SP8"
 $ geometry:sfc_POINT of length 1; first list element:  'XY' num  24.4 38.1
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Turbine"
```

There are some NA values shown here but when I

```
str(layout_shape$turbines$geometry)

sfc_POINT of length 1; first list element:  'XY' num [1:2] 24.4 38.1

head(layout_shape$turbines$geometry)
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 24.XXXX ymin: 38.XXXXX xmax: 24.XXXX ymax: 38.XXXXX
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (24.XXXXX 38.XXXXX)
```

Coordinates where replace by X by me.

Comment: I assuming you're using R

Comment: Yes sorry for not writing it